# what does *(iterator) and *(++iterator) means in below c++ code?

Tags: c++, iterator

Why *(it) in set upperbound returns index , while *(++it) in set upperbound returns value for the value greater than any value present in the set?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 set<int> s;
 s.insert(30);
 s.insert(25);
 int x=35;
 auto it = s.upper_bound(x);
 cout << *(it) << endl; //output: 2
 cout << *(++it) << endl;// output: 25
}
```

Comment: In your code example, there is no element greater than `35` in the set, therefore `it` will point to `s.end()`. Dereferencing or incrementing it is not allowed and causes undefined behavior in both cases. You could be getting any non-sense answer.

Comment: @uneven_mark the output is same as i mentioned in code comment

Comment: @NitinKumavat In C++, even if your code appears to work, it's not necessarily valid. If you enable safe iterators, you'll [get an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a8e2b81fe4661c7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(it)` does not return an index.  If `it` is an iterator that references a member of the set, then `*(it)` is equivalent to `*it`  (the `()` are not required).  It therefore accesses the corresponding member of the set.   If `it` is a past-the-end iterator, the behaviour is undefined.

`*(++it)`  first increments `it`, and then accesses the corresponding set element.  So

> ```
> cout << *(++it) << endl;
> ```

gives the same output as

```
++it;
cout << *it << endl;
```

which gives undefined behaviour if `it` was already a past-the-end iterator OR if incrementing it gives a past-the-end iterator.

In your example, the `s.upper_bound(x)` returns a past-the-end iterator, since `x` is greater than any member of the set.    Both output statements in your code therefore give undefined behaviour.